# yii2 behaviors ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT not working

Tags: activerecord, yii2

My behavior function in my model is as follows

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
        'timestamp' => [
        'class' => 'yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior',
        'attributes' => [
        ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['log_in_time' ],
        ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => ['log_in_time'],
        ],
        'value' => new Expression('NOW()'),
        ],
        ];
    }
/**
     * validation rules
     */

public function rules()
{
    return [

            ['username','filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
            ['username','required'],
            //['username','unique'],
            ['username','string', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 255],
            ['password','required'],

        ];
    }

/* Your model attribute labels */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
    /* Your other attribute labels */
    ];
}

public function scenarios()
    {
        $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
        $scenarios['login'] = ['username','log_in_time'];//Scenario Values Only Accepted
        return $scenarios;
    }
```

But it is not updating the `log_in_time` column . `log_in_time` is `DATETIME` . The value getting inserted is `0000-00-00 00:00:00` .What is the problem ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you by any chance overwriting beforeSave (or beforeInsert or beforeUpdate) in that particular model? If you do then you have to call something like

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
        ............
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I recently did something similar and spent some good time researching this only to realize that I did not call the parent before save.

If you use AttributeBehavior instead of TimestampBehavior and do exactly what you did, I believe it will work.

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
        'timestamp' => [
        'class' => 'yii\behaviors\AttributeBehavior',
        'attributes' => [
        ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['log_in_time' ],
        ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => ['log_in_time'],
        ],
        'value' => new Expression('NOW()'),
        ],
        ];
    }
```

Or you can try setting createdAtAttribute and $updatedAtAttribute to 'log_in_time' in the TimestampBehavior, that should also work.

```
     public function behaviors()
            {
                return [
                'timestamp' => [
                'class' => 'yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior',
'createdAtAttribute' =>  'log_in_time',
'updatedAtAttribute' =>  'log_in_time',
                ],
                ];
            }
```

I am not sure why it does not work like you posted.

This works for me 100%

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'blameable' => [
            'class' => BlameableBehavior::className(),
            'attributes' => [
                BaseActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['create_by', 'update_by'],
                BaseActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => 'update_by'
            ],                
        ],
        'timestamp' => [
            'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
            'attributes' => [
                BaseActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['create_time', 'update_time'],
                BaseActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => 'update_time',
            ],
            'value' => new Expression('NOW()'),
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: Just curious, why would you update the login time when you perform an update? The default application shows you how to update it on login.

Comment: I am not having beforeSave() function

Comment: Actually I am wrong, you should be able to combine the 2 just fine, just like you did. I am not sure why this is happening.

Comment: I didn't understand. Can you post the answer as a  behaviors() for better clarity ?

Comment: try the examples above

Comment: post the entire model please.

Comment: i have added rules and scenarios , Is that enough?

Comment: I have added what works for me 100%. I copy pasted from my code. Try that but I believe you have other problems with code that you have not shown.

Comment: What was the problem in the end?

Comment: I had initialized a variable with same name, $log_in_time inside the class

Comment: I can't get your code to work, can you see my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088210/yii2-timestamp-behavior-is-returning-0000-00-00-000000