# Yii2 Timestamp Behavior is returning 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2, behavior

I have copied the following code from other websites and stackoverflow answers ([yii2 behaviors ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27085990/yii2-behaviors-activerecordevent-before-insert-not-working?rq=1))  and can't get it to work:

```
 public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'timestamp' => [
                'class' => \yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior::className(),
                'attributes' => [
                    \yii\db\ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['created_at', 'updated_at'],
                    \yii\db\ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => ['updated_at'],
                ],
                'value' => new \yii\db\Expression('NOW()'),
            ],
        ];
    }
```

My model's code is:

```
namespace app\models;

use Yii;

class Setting extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /*
     * Autoupdate created_at and updated_at fields.
     */

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'timestamp' => [
                'class' => \yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior::className(),
                'attributes' => [
                    \yii\db\ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['created_at', 'updated_at'],
                    \yii\db\ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => ['updated_at'],
                ],
                'value' => new \yii\db\Expression('NOW()'),
            ],
        ];
    }
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'settings';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['value'], 'required'],
            [['value', 'reference', 'notes'], 'string'],
            [['created_at', 'updated_at'], 'safe'],
            [['property'], 'string', 'max' => 255]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'property' => 'Property',
            'value' => 'Value',
            'reference' => 'Reference',
            'created_at' => 'Created At',
            'updated_at' => 'Updated At',
            'notes' => 'Notes',
        ];
    }

    /**
     *  Get a property
     */
    public static function getSetting($property_name)
    {
        $setting = self::find()->where(['property' => $property_name])->one();
        if(is_null($setting))
            return NULL;
        else
            return $setting->value;
    }
}
```

When I create a new setting, the `created_at` and `updated_at` column is set to `0000-00-00 00:00:00` but when I then update the row again, `updated_at` works. Seems like the EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT isn't executing.

Comment: What are the columns' datatype?

Comment: Timestamp, so yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Comment: Check it with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Until a more suitable answer comes along, I achieved it using `beforeSave()`:

```
/*
* Autoupdate created_at and updated_at fields.
*/

public function beforeSave($insert)
{
   if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
      if($insert)
         $this->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
      $this->updated_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had this exact same problem in MySQL. The issue was that my database column for "created_at" was set as a timestamp datatype. I have found that you need to declare the database column as int(11) for it to work properly.

Comment: So are you suggesting it saves the date as a unix timestamp?

Comment: Yes exactly... It is saved as a Unix timestamp.

Comment: Thanks. That's useful. I have chosen to not go with this approach in the end because it's easier to search in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for time() method in Yii2 via following code:

```
Yii::$app->formatter->asTimestamp(date('Y-d-m h:i:s'))
```